# Admin tabs not loading in Chrome

Tags: joomla-4.x, administrator

I've run into an odd issue where none of the back-end tabs are displaying in Chrome. This includes pages like Global Config, New Article, and New User. When I turn on System debug, the tabs display. If I turn it off, they disappear. This is only happening in Chrome and Edge, not in Firefox. Everything was working previously. Has anyone seen something similar before? There is nothing in the browser error console that points at a potential issue. I've combed through the site error logs and nothing is jumping out as a cause of the problem, either.

Screenshots below depict the Add New Article screen with debug mode turned off, and then turned on, in the Chrome browser.

Running Joomla 4.2.3 on PHP 8.0.24

[image: Debug turned off - no tabs visible]

[image: Debug turned on - tabs visible]

Comment: Time ago I had issues with the lack of buttons at the top bar - save/save & close etc. The issue came from adblocks. Well, even I turn on adblocks today I see no issues with bars under admin area. At least you can try to disable or mention any third-party extensions. One of your screenshots gives a clear view that styles are not loaded properly or they are selectively canceled by something.

Comment: I had a client report this to me, and I don't have an ad blocker on Chrome. Since I was able to reproduce, I don't think it's a local issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @elboyler, I had such an issue on a client's computer because of his antivirus app / the browser plugin.

I would first check the plugins of the affected browsers.

Comment: This was reported to me and I was able to reproduce, so I didn't think to check browser add-ons. Since it's been a few days, I just turned off debug mode and checked all of the browsers - the tabs are back! I didn't change anything on my browsers, and only installed an update to Akeeba Backup. So who knows what happened, but now it's fixed!